# Grunt and grunt-contrib-uglify - Sources outside of localhost

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

## Question Part 1

In my current setup, I have a folder that looks like this:

```
/wwwroot <-- Hosted in localhost
/_project <-- Contains gruntfile.js
/_dev <-- Contains Source Code
```

The `wwwroot` folder is hosted in XAMPP and open in my browser. The `_project` folder contains my `gruntfile.js`, and `_dev` contains all the JS and SCSS that is compiled into JS and CSS by Grunt.

This has worked fine for a year or two, but recently, I updated my packages, and the generated sourcemaps have begun breaking. Chrome shows a blank code panel in Sources, and Firefox Dev displays a 404 error's HTML in the sources code panel. The sources were now being looked for inside the `/wwwroot` folder. Because of this, the sources 404 and aren't shown, and I can't use sourcemap debugging which I rely on.

[image: Error appearance in Chrome]
[image]

**Relevant parts of Gruntfile:**

```
uglify: {

    common: {
        options: {
            mangle: false,
            compress: true, // true or false or {}
            preserveComments: 'all', // true or 'all' or 'some'
            sourceMap : true
        },
        files: {
            // '../wwwroot/Content/includes/js/libs.js': ['../_dev/js/common/libs/*.js'],
            '../wwwroot/Content/includes/js/buildbar.js': ['../_dev/js/common/buildbar/*.js'],
            '../wwwroot/Content/includes/js/framework.js': ['../_dev/js/common/framework/*.js'],
        }
    },

}
```

Short of painfully rearranging my directory structure... how can I fix this?

## Question part 2:

I've tried using grunt-uglify-contrib's `sourceMapRoot` option as follows:

```
uglify: {

    common: {
        options: {
            mangle: false,
            compress: true, // true or false or {}
            preserveComments: 'all', // true or 'all' or 'some'
            sourceMap : true,
            sourceMapRoot: "C:/Users/quint/Documents/Github/build-siteengine/a/a/a/a"
        },
        files: {
            // '../wwwroot/Content/includes/js/libs.js': ['../_dev/js/common/libs/*.js'],
            '../wwwroot/Content/includes/js/buildbar.js': ['../_dev/js/common/buildbar/*.js'],
            '../wwwroot/Content/includes/js/framework.js': ['../_dev/js/common/framework/*.js'],
        }
    },

}
```

For some reason, though, the paths that show in the Sources panel in Firefox Dev are missing four directories, hence why I've added the `/a/a/a/a`. Why would this be happening?

This also doesn't solve my problem, since in Firefox Dev clicking on the line numbers open the file in the browser and don't take me to the line of code in the debugger, and in Chrome there is no effect.

Comment: Can you remove the leading underscore and try again? I ran into the same issue with GitHub pages a while back. Forgive me for not looking too deeply into this yet, but if that doesn't do anything I'll dig into it.

Comment: Thanks @suzumakes, I've re-run it after removing the leading underscore from the folder names (changing the folder names and the references in the gruntfile, but no change.

Comment: Hey @Gandalf I've found this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/pull/122) and it looks like (without digging too much into it, sorry!) there was a fix for this. Can you `npm i -g npm-check-updates`, `ncu -a`, and `npm update` in the directory of your Gruntfile and rerun your uglify? That'll bump your package.json to the latest and if that doesn't work I'll look at this again when I'm not at work. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @suzumakes - I've since reorganised my code and I'm coming along fine, but I'll do a fork of my code tomorrow and try as you suggested, in case it helps someone with the same issue. :)